# How to login from Java/Rest client into an app with spring security

Tags: java, spring, rest, authentication

Our application is built with Spring (MVC, transactions, authentication, etc). We use LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint for authentication (please see below for the whole spring security xml). The web client (jsp) uses j_spring_security_check form to login to this app. The app has REST API and the browser code (web client) make REST calls to the app. So far so good and everything works fine. We are writing code in Java to test the app - end-to-end testing using REST calls (similar to how the real client, web client in my case, invokes the app). I am using Apache's HttpClient on the tests side to make REST calls to the app. Do you know how to authenticate/login to the app from the Java-written tests code? Any guidance is much appreciated. Thanks, prams.

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" filters="none"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/agentMsg" filters="none"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/wait" filters="none"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/systemConfig/**" filters="none"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/heartbeat" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reposTracking" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/alerts/sev" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:form-login  
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1" 
        authentication-success-handler-ref="mcLoginSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="mcLoginFailureHandler"
    />
    <security:remember-me/>
    <security:logout success-handler-ref="mcLogoutHandler"/>
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter"/>
    <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
</security:http>

<!--  needed for remember-me service -->
<bean id="customUserDetailService" class="com.mycompany.admin.tools.webui.beans.MyCompanyUserDetailsService"/>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="vuiAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>


<bean id="vuiAuthenticationProvider" class="com.mycompany.admin.tools.webui.beans.VuiMycompanyUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailService"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder"    ref="md5PasswordEncoder"/>
</bean>

<bean id="md5PasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>      

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"></property>
</bean>

 <bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    <property name="expiredUrl" value="/login"/>
    <!-- <property name="redirectStrategy" value=""></property> -->
 </bean>

 <bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
      <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
      <property name="maximumSessions" value="-1" /> <!-- no limit on number of session per user -->
 </bean>

 <bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<bean id="mcLogoutHandler" class="com.mycompany.admin.tools.webui.servlets.McLogoutHandler"/>
<bean id="mcLoginSuccessHandler" class="com.mycompany.admin.tools.webui.servlets.McLoginSuccessHandler"/>
<bean id="mcLoginFailureHandler" class="com.mycompany.admin.tools.webui.servlets.McLoginFailureHandler"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if your tests are making http requests then they are not unit tests, but functional tests.

If you want to make such tests work you will basically have to go through the steps that are performed when you log in from a browser: `POST` credentials to `/j_spring_security_check`, and make sure that the `JSESSIONID` cookie that was set in the response is sent back to the server with each subsequent call.

Comment: RE:  "if your tests are making http requests then they are not unit tests" -- do explain why that disqualifies them from being unit tests

Comment: @foampile: Unit tests normally involve checking if a specific function of one or a couple of classes works correctly. If a test sends http requests and the software being tested is anything else than an http client library, especially if it's a webapp as in this case, it means that it requires the complete application stack running as a black-box. The outcome of such a test depends on so many different factors (code in many layers, configuration, infrastructure setup, etc.) that I cannot see how it could be considered a unit test. If you work by a different definition of unit test then sorry:)

Comment: HTTP in this case is just the protocol for remotely invoking a function (unit) that is formatted as a RESTful web service.  whether you go over HTTP or invoke the function from a client that communicates to it at an API level in its own language does not really change the unit nature of the test.  testing that a web service returns "XYZ" vs testing that a fellow java class returns "XYZ" are both unit tests regardless of which protocol you follow to invoke your function

Comment: @foampile: I agree that the protocol doesn't change the nature of the test, so I wouldn't consider it a unit test either if the web service was invoked at the java API level, _unless_ all the dependencies of the implementing class (e.g. various injected services/repositories) were mocked out. Otherwise by the time the service returns "XYZ", the test has exercised a range of different units, not a single one in isolation.

Comment: the term "unit" may not apply to my tests. I am basically doing end-to-end testing using REST calls (similar to how the real client, web client in my case, invokes the app). I am using Apache's HttpClient on the tests side to make REST calls to the app.

Comment: @zagyi, can you tell me how to get the jsession ID when I login? When I execute curl with verbose option, I can see the jsessionid. This is an option that I can go with (which is more work - prase the output, etc), but wondering if there is any way to easily see the jsessionid when I do the login using REST call from Java.

Comment: @prams: Sorry, I didn't want to start a war about the definition of unit testing. Apologies if my remark about that sounded too harsh. About cookie handling: I think Apache HttpClient supports automatic cookie management. Chances are that you don't have to do anything else than using the same `DefaultHttpClient` instance for posting the credentials and for sending the other reqest afterwards. Please review the [related docs here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html).

Comment: hi, i am able to successfully  authenticate into the app. But, the subsequent requests don't reach the controller (app uses Spring MVC) method at all and sends back the html page that as if the user is not authenticated. It looks like it is setting the cookies. When I am printing the cookies (used httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies()), it prints a different jsessionid for every request. Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: and is different jsessionid the reason why the app thinks the user is not authenticated?
<br/>
Here are the cookies, one for each request (see that jsessionid is different for each request):  
<br/>
cookies: [[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: 1x5i3b0lbf5o7xv52kjh0vu89][domain: 127.0.0.1][path: /webui][expiry: null]]  <br/>

cookies: [[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: t05vbrffqv6t1xcygps9l6jaz][domain: 127.0.0.1][path: /webui][expiry: null]]  <br/>

cookies: [[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: 8v5i5ofbgr201kh2txxale674][domain: 127.0.0.1][path: /webui][expiry: null]]

Comment: Are you sure that the login is successful? Enable debug level logging on packages `org.springframework.security.authentication` and `org.springframework.security.web.authentication` to check what really happens on the server side. And of course the client must send back **the same** `JSESSIONID` that the server set after the successful authentication, because the authentication is tied to the session.

Answer (score 0):

You should test one level lower. Test your business logic in unit test manner. Why do you need to test if RestEasy/CXF/Jersey/whatever is calling methods properly? Do you need to test if spring-security works fine? I guess someone has written unit-tests for that already.

For integration testing read Spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing). You can set-up a bit simpler context without authentication and call MockHttpRequest.

For REST testing you may also use SoapUI.

Comment: Thx for your response. I am not testing the spring security here. In order to invoke app's RESP api, I need to login first and login is where I am struggling.